# Проблема с тернарным оператором ?:

Tags: c++

Почему такой код:

```
bool foo() const
{
    _variable ? return true : return false;
}
```

Выдает ошибку компиляции:

> error C2059: syntax error: 'return'

Компилятор Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: Потому что `return _variable ? true : false;`, наверное...

Comment: Мда ) `return _variable? true : false` как минимум. А еще что мешает сделать так: `return _variable;`?

Comment: а какой тип у _variable?

Comment: @ gil9red, думаю тип не имеет значения для того, чтоб, конкретно для данного случая,   Uraty был прав...

Comment: Такой же [вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3918203/return-statement-in-ternary-operator-c) на enSO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Тернарная операция содержит условие и значения  удовлетворяющее условию и неудовлетворяющее. 
return завершает выполнение функции и возвращает элемент управления в вызывающую функцию  Выполнение возобновляется в вызывающей функции в точке сразу после вызова, т.е. это действие, а не значение... Возвращать это, если..., ну а если нет, то  другое, а не: если это, то возвращать...

Answer (score 2):

return должен быт перед _variable ?

```
bool foo() const
{
    return _variable;
}
```